# Combine two files and keep the non match lines

Tags: bash, awk

I am studying the sed command but I have a problem when combining 2 files.

file1.txt

```
A       1
C       3
E       5
```

file2.txt

```
1 John Lennon
2 Mariah carey
3 Cool & The Gang
4 Westlife
5 Red Hot Chili Peppers
```

desired output

```
1 John Lennon A
2 Mariah Carey
3 Cool & The Gang C
4 Westlife
5 Red Hot Chili Peppers E
```

I try to make awk script like this:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{seen[$1]=$2; next} $1 in seen{seen[$1]=seen[$1] OFS $2} END{ for (e in seen) print e, seen[e]}' file2.txt file1.txt | sort -V
```

but this output only display one word of the singer (John, Mariah, Cool, Westlife, and Red) and does not display the singer's full name. Is something wrong with my script?

Comment: There is not one, but a lot of errors in your code.

Comment: In order to explain what you do wrong, one should understand why, in your opinion, it should work.  Explain what exactly should be, in your opinion, the result of each line of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use following code, I have made minor changes in your attempt.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  val=$1
  $1=""
  sub(/^ +/,"")
  seen[val]=$0
  next
}
$2 in seen{
  print $2,seen[$2],$1
  b[$2]
  next
}
END{
  for(i in seen){
    if(!(i in b)){
      print i,seen[i]
    }
  }
}
' file2.txt file1.txt | sort -V
```

Output will be as follows.

```
1 John Lennon A
2 Mariah carey
3 Cool & The Gang C
4 Westlife
5 Red Hot Chili Peppers E
```

***Problem with OP's attempted code:***

- OP is making index for seen array as $1(which is correct) BUT making value as ONLY $2 which is NOT right, because $2 will catch only `John` OR `Mariah` and so on.
- That is the reason why OP's attempt is NOT giving complete output.
- Also OP is using $1 index of Input_file1(file1.txt) to check if its present in seen array or not, it should be $2 there.

Comment: Great explanation

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using a fairly simple 2 step process in `awk` and there is no need to use `sort` since we can process `file2` in second phase:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{seen[$2]=$1; next} $1 in seen{$0 = $0 OFS seen[$1]} 1' file1 file2
```

```
1 John Lennon A
2 Mariah carey
3 Cool & The Gang C
4 Westlife
5 Red Hot Chili Peppers E
```

Answer (score 1):

**If** the columns of the two files are separated by tabs instead of spaces (Looks like the first one is, second one I don't know; unfortunately SO's markdown is not tab friendly), it's a trivial [`join`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/join.1.html):

```
$ join -12 -21 -o 0,2.2,1.1 -t$'\t' -a2 <(sort -t$'\t' -k2,2 file1.txt) <(sort -t$'\t' -k1,1 file2.txt)
1   John Lennon A
2   Mariah carey    
3   Cool & The Gang C
4   Westlife    
5   Red Hot Chili Peppers   E
```

(`join` requires its files to be sorted lexicographically on the join column, not numerically, hence the `sort`s).

If there's just a space between the number and the band in file2, convert it to a tab first with `sed`:

```
join -12 -21 -o 0,2.2,1.1 -t$'\t' -a2 <(sort -t$'\t' -k2,2 file1.txt) <(sed 's/ /\t/' file2.txt | sort -t$'\t' -k1,1)
```